# Why docker command connects to daemon via tcp by default

Tags: docker, ubuntu

Docker is configured by default to listen on socket (Ubuntu 18.04).

> $ ps aux | grep docker
>   root      1966  0.2  0.4 1451444 69700 ?
>   Ssl  09:57   0:01 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
>   --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

But when I run `docker ps` it raises:

> $ docker ps
>   Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at
>   tcp://127.0.0.1:2375. Is the docker daemon running?

I need to specify:

> $ docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock ps
>   CONTAINER ID        IMAGE
>   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
>   NAMES 7ffd2dc852f2        jwilder/nginx-proxy
>   "/app/docker-entrypo…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes
>   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   nginx-proxy

Then works fine, but why cli wants to connect daemon by default via tcp? How to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

docker client uses `DOCKER_HOST` environment value if set otherwise default to unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Check if you have DOCKER_HOST environment variable set?